# Почему std::count() возвращает знаковое число?

Tags: c++

Почему алгоритм `std::count()` возвращает `difference_type`, ведь это знаковое число, а количество вхождений чего-то во что-то может быть 0+, т.е. беззнаковое число?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С одной стороны, `std::count` хочет/вынужден брать тип результата из `std::iterator_traits`, а там просто нет подходящего беззнакового типа. Так как `std::iterator_traits<>::difference_type` по своему замыслу должен быть достаточен для подсчета разности между двумя итераторами, он должен быть достаточен и для результата `std::count`. А то, что он оказался знаковым - лишь небольшая побочная неувязочка. При разработке `std::iterator_traits<>` туда стоило бы добавить некий отдельный беззнаковый `count_type` (или `size_type`), но в свое время этого не сделали.

С другой стороны, в дизайне стандартной библиотеки С++ по-прежнему теплится отвратительная практика совать знаковые типы туда, где им не место, только ради того, чтобы уменьшить вероятность совершения неквалифицированными программистами ошибок из-за смешения знаковых и беззнаковых типов. Например, `std::shared_ptr<>::use_count()` возвращает знаковый результат якобы именно по этой причине.